# How I can probe and place some wires/probes on that chip?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the following chip:

[image: Flash memory chip I want to analyze]

And I want to analyze it without desoldering. The chip "legs" are not the long one where you can plase some cables with temporary soldering. Also I do not want to desolder it.

Are there some sore of interfacing and analyzing it with some sort of microneedles/special probes? As you can see the solder interface are some small solder "balls".

Also, how I can avoid whilst probing to not fry the rest of the boards as well? I was thinking to apply the necessary voltage if needed so I can actively interface it without powering the device on.

The chip is a flash memory chip and I want to dump its contents to my pc.

Comment: Chip seems to have 4 pins on eahc side according to documentation.
https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7770/MX35LF1GE4AB,%203V,%201Gb,%20v1.8.pdf

There are 4 "balls" on one side and 4 on the other as well. So seems inplaysible to me that are only power lines.

Comment: I think I would look for another place on the board to attach those wires.

Answer (score 3):

> The chip "legs" are not the long one where you can plase some cables with temporary soldering.

Soldering seems to me in this case by *far* the easiest solution: the datasheet says the pads extend 0.2mm vertically, which really is plenty to whet it with flux, and solder a thin wire to it.

So, really, this is a job for electronic flux, thin wire ("magnet wire" / "enamel wire" with 2mm of insulating lacquer scraped off) and a soldering iron with a thin tip.

Building a rig to attach really finely-tipped needle probes to this will be much harder, more expensive in acquisition and error prone.

Comment: Wouold solrering iron tip such as this  https://tinyurl.com/4mnteknr
 suffice?
Woudl you reccomend curved or straight tip?

Comment: The packaging seems more like WSON one.

Comment: It's unlikely that simply soldering wires on will work. The chip is connected to other logic that would R/W. You may have to power the board and hold an MCU in reset to ensure you can drive the signals, otherwise you simply cause the inbuilt intrinsic diodes in the drive logic to partially power the board.

Comment: @JackCreasey fair point, a solution to that is often to unsolder part of the SMPS that typically powers these devices (or the linear regulator between SMPS and device). But you're right!

Comment: So if I somehow manage the MCU in loop mode I can tamper the flash memort chip as long as I want to right with the device powered on?

Comment: The MCU is a RTL8685PB Soc without a know datasheet.